# Write unformatted string using <![CDATA]]> with Postgresql

Tags: xml, postgresql

I have to build an sql query giving this xml flow.

```
<product sku="B8B301">
   <descriptif_court>
       <![CDATA[<p>1 activité de sport de glisse </p>
    <p>Pour 1 à 4 personnes</p>
    <p>110 activités de sport de glisse: jet-ski, wakeboard, airboard, motoneige, sky fly…</p>]]>
    </descriptif_court>
</product>
```

But I d'ont know to do this.

I try

```
SELECT    XMLSERIALIZE(
    DOCUMENT

    xmlelement(
        NAME product,
        XMLATTRIBUTES (a.sku AS sku),
        xmlconcat(
            xmlelement( NAME descriptif_court,  concat('<![CDATA[', a.descriptif_court, ']]>'))
        )
    ) AS TEXT
)
FROM (

       SELECT
         b.code           AS sku,
         b.short_description
       FROM box b
         where b.code='B8B301'
     ) a
```

The result is :

```
<product sku="B8B301">
  <descriptif_court>
    &lt;![CDATA[&lt;p&gt;1 activité de sport de glisse &lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Pour 1 à 4 personnes&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;110 activités de sport de glisse: jet-ski, wakeboard, airboard, motoneige, sky fly…&lt;/p&gt;]]&gt;
  </descriptif_court>
</product>
```

I don't want to escape xml tags inside the `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>`

Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly tell `xmlelement()` that the `content` parameter is already a well-formed XML by passing `xml` data instead of `text` so that the function doesn't have to bother escaping the content. So in the context of your query you only need to cast the result of `concat()` to `xml`:

```
...
xmlconcat(
    xmlelement( NAME descriptif_court,  
        concat('<![CDATA[', a.descriptif_court, ']]>')::xml
    )
)
...
```

**<kbd>[`db-fiddle demo`](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/anTvEVCg2cT3n9nUraxgRD/0)</kbd>**